# Date & time is not inserted proper for special price while add product in nopcommerc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-ui, nopcommerce

I am using nopcommerce version 3.60 & my database is on SQL server 2012.
My store date time is `UTC+5.30` that I have set after refer this post http://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/t/12054/where-does-the-default-timezone-come-from.aspx

I have try to enter special price start date is `1-jan-2015` and  special price end date is `31-jan-2016` and try to save this but I got 
error of

> "The value '1/31/2016 12:00 AM' is not valid for Special price end
>   date."

That I didn't get it why this comes I have enter proper and in text box it shows `1/31/2016 12:00 AM` and if I change it with `31/1/2015 12:)) AM` it will be saved and show in special price end date textbox is `31-Jan-16 12:00:00 AM`.

So I am facing this issue. Please provide me some setting for this bug.

So it is Nopcommerce bug. Is any one have face this issue tell me that, and also checked in database of product table it has datatype is `datetime`.

Comment: Looks like a culture issue. What is the culture on the server?

Comment: @Stephen Muecke Where can i find culture on server i am running nopcommerce on local host. guide me to find it culture on server ?

Comment: How do you enter ? Manualy or using calendar control ?